# How i can include a SASS mixin with a variable?

Tags: css, sass

It is possible to @include a @mixin with a variable like $mixin-var?

```
@mixin hide{
    background: transparent;
}

$mixin-var: hide;

.hide{
    @include $mixin-var;
}
```

If yes how I can do that?

Comment: Curious what the use case for this is.

Comment: Yes, why? Why not include the mixin direct? `@include hide;` ?

Comment: If I have $map: (hide: hide) and I want create with @each the class with hide name including the hide mixin, how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't thing so. The only sass way that it exists for the moment is use @include [mixin_name] like the sass documentation says https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin